# Merc C220d misfire at revs above 2000 rpm

Tags: diesel, mercedes-benz, misfire

Ok I need help. My merc C220d w203 is having a proble it feels and looks like a misfire. It happen constant when I rev above 2000rpm to 3000rpm. Once the engine drops back to idle it take it from 5 seconds to a 60 seconds but it gets its self back under control and stops misfiring. While it is misfiring loads of white/Blue smoke comes out. And it stinks of unburnt desiel fuel.

I have plugged in a code reader there are zero codes and no EML. I'm not sure what could be causing it, it just started out of the blue this morning

Comment: It sounds like there's a stuck injector where it's always on. I believe they call this *stiction*. There are products which can take care of this for you like [Howes Meaner Power Kleaner](http://www.howeslube.com/meanerpowerkleaner.php) and [Hot Shot Stiction Eliminator](http://www.hotshotsecret.com/shop/stiction-eliminator/).

Comment: If this was the case would it not have a bad idle?

Comment: I think a better way of putting what I'm trying to say is the injector is slow to close all the way. Getting the injectors cleaned is a great (and cheap) first step to diagnosing your issue. It happens quite readily and is easily dealt with.

Comment: @paulster2  Aren't your comments here better posed as an answer?

Comment: It's had a lot of redex diesel Run though it of late and it's running Shell V-Power Diesel at the moment which is supposed to help them keep clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since this has been on here a while it turned out that while standard diagnostics did not get any codes a star diagnostics identified that the engine was moving a little too much turned out to be an engine mount was loose.

The reason for taking it into the Garage, in the end, was that the car started applying a Rev limiting factor it would lock me to no higher than 2000 RPM but no Engine Management light would come on.